# Создание нового массива (evenArr), содержащего только четные элементы исходного массива(array)

Tags: c#, массивы

```
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int evenCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
       if(array[i] % 2 == 0){evenCount++}
    }
    int[] evenArr = new int[evenCount];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
       if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
       {
           evenArr[j++] = array[i];
       }
    }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", evenArr));
) выдает RangeError
// Использование ArrayList запрещено
// Использовать методы класса Array запрещено
// Разрешено использовать только циклы и условные операции
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете один индекс для обоих массивов, а нужны разные

```
for(int i = 0, int j = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        evenArr[j++] = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `int i = 0, int j = 0;` не знал про такую конструкцию)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Но проблема еще и в том, что новый массив имеет такую же длину, как исходный, но конец массива заполнен нулями по дефолту. А нужно, чтобы новый массив имел длину только четных чисел...

Comment: @ВладимирВаганов Нет, так не должно быть, проверьте значение evenCount

Comment: @ВладимирВаганов MBo, тегание ника с пробелом должно быть без пробела :)

Comment: evenCount я использую для инициализации нового массива для четных значений. Но цикл тогда не запускается, поскольку новый массив короче, чем исходный и выдает RangeError

Comment: Вы правильно используете evenCount, и когда не все элементы чётные, его значение должно быть меньше длины первого массива. RangeError у вас был из-за того, что вы пытались писать в те же индексы, что и у первого - я ведь показал, как это исправить. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в конце последнюю версию кода, если он ещё не работает, как надо

Comment: Куда у вас делась проверка на чётность в первом цикле???

Comment: Да, точно, моя невнимательность и спешка)) Теперь всё заработало как надо, Спасибо Вам огромное!!!

Comment: OK, не забывайте  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer